Root cause for failed UART interface on SBC
I could use some help troubleshooting an SBC (KSTR-SAMA5D27) that will no longer communicate via some of its UART pins and what could be root cause, so I can prevent future failures.
As part of a prototype I'm communicating with a cell module (Ublox SARA-R510S-01B) and communication was working reliably. I set this up to perform stability testing for a couple months and I recently discovered it no longer responding.
Based on the following loopback testing there seems to be some (not visible) damage to the SBC's CTS/RTS interface.
Opening the port in minicom with hardware flow control disabled with Tx and Rx bridged works fine. Opening the port with CTS and RTS bridged, the SBC hangs.
Current between CTS and RTS when shorted is 1.7mA whereas on a new healthy SBC it is 0.01mA.
Both devices use 1.8V signalling.
The "risky" environmental factors I'm aware of are:

One of the SBC's GPIO pins was exposed to voltage close to the absolute max.

The PWR_ON input of the cell module has an internal 10kohm pullup to its 4.08V supply. I had this connected directly to an output pin on the SBC which is set to use 1.8V logic. The SBC pulses this low to turn on/off the module. It doesn't say for outputs but the SBC datasheet lists 4.0V as the absolute max for inputs. My next revision will have an intermediary MOSFET but is it possible this overvoltage damaged UART I/O? The SBC output that drives PWR_ON still seems to work fine.

The SBC was power cycled every few seconds for a couple days, accidently.

Due to my power supply being not quite able to supply necessary charge current during a low battery condition the charge current caused it to repeatedly "hiccup mode" reset itself until I intervened. I'm not sure if the UART failure happened at the same time.
Is there any further inspection of the failed SBC I can perform to narrow down a likely root cause?

What have you actually measured on the circuit board? If you suspect a short occurred somewhere, how do you know this? Have you measured any voltage or resistance? Have you used an oscilloscope to measure any waveforms on the UART lines (Tx, Rx, RTS, CTS)? Have you used a thermal camera to see where a short could be? There's not much to go off of right now. If your battery voltage did dip, your board would draw more current, and it could be possible that this excess current could have fried something inside of the MCU.

Are you sure about 1.8V IO voltages? The manual says jumper shorted is 1.8V and silkscreen says jumper shorted is 3.3V. Also how do you power the modules? If supply of one module rises to 1V8 while the other is still 0V then bad things will happen.

@Justme Manual is incorrect, silkscreen is correct - I confirmed with measurements. You mean if the SBC powers on before the cell module it will cause problems? cell module is powered from the SBC 5V supply through a linear regulator to give 4.08V. so I expect there's some small delay at startup.

@davegravy It causes problems either way - it does not matter if CPU is at 0V while module is powered or if module is at 0V while CPU is powered. UART interface outputs will idle with a push-pull output set high.

@Colin I don't have evidence there was any short, sorry if my description misled. I have measured RTS (0V) and CTS (1.8V) pins while unconnected and while the port is opened in the OS. Also measured 1.7mA flowing between these two when connected.

@Justme if the SBC is on but doesn't have the UART open, is it still a risk if the cell module is powered down? From the SBC I can sense the cell module is ON, I could restrict the SBC from opening the port if this condition isn't satisfied.

@davegravy what do you mean by "uart open"? Simply initializing the IO pins for UART can push them high even if you don't "open it in Linux" for communicating.

@Justme module needs to sleep (power down) while SBC remains on. Is there some protection that can be added between devices to safely allow this operation?

@davegravy There sure is, chips exist that are especially designed for helping interface between powered and unpowered chips.
